# Configuration Manager holds old configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Currently my configuration manager holds several configurations I have created:
[image]

Everything is fine except one configuration - `Debug like exe`. I have created and deleted it in the past. Actually this configuration set is not visible in configuration manager.

[image]

But why it appears in property page? And how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your project file (right click the project at the solution explorer, and choose 'Edit project file' or 'unload'+'edit'), and search for the string 'debug like exe'.  My guess is you'd find some remnants from the configuration removal, you should be able to safely delete them - just make sure to backup the vcxproj beforehand.